# Difference between non-Hermitian and PT-symmetric systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, cpt-symmetry

Can anyone explain me the difference between non-Hermitian and PT-symmetric systems (in terms of the Hamiltonian)? Are they two mutually exclusive things?